# How to find out which view file is loaded in Joomla 3.2?

Tags: php, joomla

I'am templating the website under the Joomla 3.2.0 for HikaShop ecommerce component, and would like to find out which file is loaded with following code, so I could correctly override the styles for specific file.

The filename I'a working with is `root\templates\MY_TEMPLATE\html\com_hikashop\user\registration.php`. Inside that file there is a small part of code which underloads custom fields I would like to override with custom styles:

```
<div class="address-fields">
    <?php
        $this->type = 'address';
        echo $this->loadTemplate();
    ?>
</div>
```

Anyone knows which filepath is exactly loaded with the following `$this->loadTemplate();` ?

Comment: I don't know about Hikashop views but as a workaround you can insert `echo "This view is loaded!"` inside your view files and rotate them to see which one is loaded.

Comment: @ilias - To do so, I need to insert that comment inside the correct file, which is called from `echo $this->loadTemplate();`, but as I said, i have no clue which file it loads exactly.

Comment: @ilias means it is not as though there are thousands of layout files for that view (I would hope). `loadTemplate()` without an argument is going to load the default.php file either from your template or if not present there, from the `tmpl` folder for that view in the component.  But the way that is coded right now looks like it would put you into a loop since the `view.html.php` file usually loads the default. But I guess if they have it working they have it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are using it the same way as it is used here, but they explain it as if the parameters you pass in the function `loadTemplate()`, actually as `loadTemplate(address)` would be files in your case found in registration_address.php

hey, It's worth a shot checking it out

[***SEE HERE***](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides)

Comment: You are right, this is the way the Joomla Templating works, but in case with HikaShop component, it works sometimes different. As you said, I should search for `user\registration_ADDRESS.php`, but there isn't any, even `user/address.php` is missing, that's why I'am confused.

Comment: Interesting. Is this site live? Can I see the url?

Comment: That's okay, it will automatically know that if you do loadTemplate('address') from inside registration.php  it will look for registration_address.php.   It's very similar to what you see in the com_content category folder with the blog layout.

Comment: @LOTUSMS - no, sorry, it's on my localhost. I can't do a `var_dump()` on live site. As the answer wasn't exactly concerned to my problem, can I do something to feed you with some more information ? At the same time, if I will find out what's going on there, I will keep you updated. Thanks anyway